# Can't figure out js for customizing google map.

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, customization

I'm fresh of the boat when it comes to js. The map appears in place, but styling doesn't work.

It keeps telling me that I have mostly code and not enough information so I'm just writing this so it will go away.

```
    function initialize() {

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.695301,-82.401196),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

          [
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#2e2d2d" }
    ]
  },{
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#facf0b" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#808080" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#808080" }
    ]
  },{
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style

```
  map.set('styles', [
  {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#000000' },
      { weight: 1.6 }
    ]
  }]);
```

Use the variable that you create the map (var map) and set the style.

example:

```
var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
      { saturation: -20 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 },
      { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

Comment: It's not working. I don't think I'm putting the code in the right place.